# Format stack trace to manually return in API response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

Currently it is returning a single unintelligible chunk composed of multiple of these things glued one next to the other like this:

> at ProyectX.Services.Service.Validate(IList 1 myParam) in
> C:\\Repositories\\projectx\\src\\ProyectX.Services\\Service.cs:line
> 116\r\n at ProyectX.Services.Service.Validate(IList 1 myParam) in
> C:\\Repositories\\projectx\\src\\ProyectX.Services\\Service.cs:line
> 116\r\n

Goal:

> at ProyectX.Services.Service.Validate(IList 1 myParam) in C:\Repositories\projectx\src\ProyectX.Services\Service.cs:line 116
>
> at ProyectX.Services.Service.Validate(IList 1 myParam) in C:\Repositories\projectx\src\ProyectX.Services\Service.cs:line 116

I tried with

```
Regex.Unescape(exception.StackTrace)

JsonSerializer.Serialize(exception.StackTrace, new JsonSerializerOptions() {WriteIndented = true });
```

The middleware is in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlerMiddleware>();
```

Middleweare:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using ProyectX.Domain.Exceptions;
using ProyectX.Domain.Models;

namespace ProyectX.API.Middleware
{
    public class ErrorHandlerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public ErrorHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                var response = context.Response;
                response.ContentType = "application/json";

                switch (exception)
                {
                    case InvalidOperationException:
                        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                        break;
                    default:
                        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                        break;
                }

                var details = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Message", exception.Message },
                };

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    details.Add("StackTrace", exception.StackTrace);
                }

                var errorResponse = new ErrorResponseModel(exception, details);
                var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(errorResponse);

                await response.WriteAsync(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ErrorResponseModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ProyectX.Domain.Models
{
    public class ErrorResponseModel
    {
        public ErrorResponseModel(Exception ex, Dictionary<string, string> details)
        {
            Type = ex.GetType().Name;
            Details = details;
        }

        public string Type { get; set; }

        public IDictionary<string, string> Details { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very improbable the message contains literal ``\r\n`` sequences. Are you looking at this with a debugger? The VS debugger has visualizations available for strings that presents them unescaped. If you're looking at this as a JSON string, that's escaped too and that's fine (in fact it's *required*); it should be unescaped on deserialization, however. TL;DR: you likely don't need to do anything with the strings, but change the way you're looking at the strings yourself.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That is the API response looking it on Postman or the browser Network inspector

Comment: Yeah, but are they decoding the JSON response or not? The raw JSON will of course have the strings escaped, but deserialized JSON should not. If an inspector/GUI isn't formatting multi-line strings as multi-line, there's nothing you can do in your serialization to fix that. `exception.StackTrace` does *not* contain ``\r\n``, that's all serialization -- not only can you not fix that, you shouldn't, as the result would be invalid JSON. If you really wanted to you could parse the stack frames and serialize the error as an array of those (for better reading). That's quite some work though.

Comment: The net core default implementation returns exception stack traces properly, with the same Postman and browser settings.

Comment: Then there's probably double escaping going on when `CustomeErrorResponseModel` gets serialized. This is, I assume, ASP.NET MVC? Perhaps tag it as such (and give complete code of the model/controller).

Comment: Added as per your request

Comment: There should be a backquote between `IList` and `1`.  What happened to it?  (Perhaps that's a hint as to what is mangling your text.)

Comment: I removed it because StackOverflow was adding format to that part

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you make changes to your `ErrorResponseModel` class so that your dictionary accepts object type as value, like `Dictionary<string, object>`. Here comes the idea, with object type the dictionary value can accept adding string OR string array.

So for your `StackTrace`, you can split it into multiple lines using split by "\r\n" and get a string array of it, that I can pass to my `StackTrace` value.

So let's come to your model:

```
public class ErrorResponseModel
{
    public ErrorResponseModel(Exception ex, Dictionary<string, object> details)
    {
        Type = ex.GetType().Name;
        Details = details;
    }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, object> Details { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the part that handles the exception:

```
var details = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "Message", exception.Message} ,
};

var lines = exception.StackTrace?.Split("\r\n").Select(e => e.TrimStart());
details.Add("StackTrace", lines);

var errorResponse = new ErrorResponseModel(exception, details);

var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(errorResponse, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true });
```

All this returns the following:

[image]

Comment: Although this deals with the \r\n characters and is useful as a workaround, I think there is something else going on here as the other weird characters still persist like \\ and others.

Comment: @user33276346 remember this double \\ is just a representing a single backslash, if your concern is about presenting them as just single backslash.

Answer (score 3):

#### Exception information model using StackTrace and StackFrame classes

There's a [StackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) class which can help you to get list of [StackFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stackframe?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) objects. Each frame, includes information like:

- Line Number
- Method (Class, Assembly)
- Code File

Looking into ASP.NET Core [ErrorPage](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Shared/ErrorPage/Views/ErrorPage.cshtml?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and [DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/DeveloperExceptionPage/DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.cs?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#L227) you will see the framework has created a model class including the exception information like stack frame and then in the error page has formatted the model and showed in a readable format.

This is how Exception class also generates the `StackTrace`: by calling [StackTrace.ToString](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#mscorlib/system/diagnostics/stacktrace.cs,f4bbb1fa2df8ea1f) which gets the stack frames and format above information in a string.

You can also do the same and generate the string in a better format, or as a better idea, create an exception or stacktrace model and let the formatting be done later.

For example, this is the exception model (including stacktrace) that you can have:

```
{
  "Message":"Attempted to divide by zero.",
  "StackFrames":[
    {
      "LineNumber":13,
      "Method":"Main(String[] args)",
      "Class":"SampleConsoleApp.Program",
      "AssemblyName":"SampleConsoleApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
      "AssemblyFile":"file:///C:/SampleConsoleApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/SampleConsoleApp.dll",
      "CodeFile":"C:\\SampleConsoleApp\\Program.cs"
    },
    {
      "LineNumber":23,
      "Method":"Divide(Int32 x, Int32 y)",
      "Class":"SampleConsoleApp.Program",
      "AssemblyName":"SampleConsoleApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
      "AssemblyFile":"file:///C:/SampleConsoleApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/SampleConsoleApp.dll",
      "CodeFile":"C:\\SampleConsoleApp\\Program.cs"
     }
  ],
  "InnerException":null
}
```

Above json string is created from my exception model:

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var model = ExceptionModel.Create(ex);

    // You can convert it to json and store it
    // Or format it and write to log 
}
```

**ExceptionModel including StackTrace**

Here is how I've implemented exception model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
public class ExceptionModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<StackFrameModel> StackFrames { get; set; }
    public ExceptionModel InnerException { get; set; }
    public static ExceptionModel Create(Exception ex = null)
    {
        var trace = ex == null ? new StackTrace(true) : new StackTrace(ex, true);
        var model = new ExceptionModel();
        model.Message = ex?.Message;
        model.StackFrames = trace.GetFrames().Reverse()
            .Select(x => new StackFrameModel()
        {
            LineNumber = x.GetFileLineNumber(),
            Method = GetMethodSignature(x.GetMethod()),
            Class = x.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType?.FullName,
            AssemblyName = x.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType?.Assembly?.FullName,
            AssemblyFile = x.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType?.Assembly?.CodeBase,
            CodeFile = x.GetFileName(),
        });
        if (ex?.InnerException != null)
            model.InnerException = ExceptionModel.Create(ex.InnerException);
        return model;
    }
    private static string GetTypeName(Type type)
    {
        return type?.FullName?.Replace('+', '.');
    }
    private static string GetMethodSignature(MethodBase mb)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(mb.Name);

        // deal with the generic portion of the method
        if (mb is MethodInfo && ((MethodInfo)mb).IsGenericMethod)
        {
            Type[] typars = ((MethodInfo)mb).GetGenericArguments();
            sb.Append("[");
            int k = 0;
            bool fFirstTyParam = true;
            while (k < typars.Length)
            {
                if (fFirstTyParam == false)
                    sb.Append(",");
                else
                    fFirstTyParam = false;

                sb.Append(typars[k].Name);
                k++;
            }
            sb.Append("]");
        }

        // arguments printing
        sb.Append("(");
        ParameterInfo[] pi = mb.GetParameters();
        bool fFirstParam = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < pi.Length; j++)
        {
            if (fFirstParam == false)
                sb.Append(", ");
            else
                fFirstParam = false;

            String typeName = "<UnknownType>";
            if (pi[j].ParameterType != null)
                typeName = pi[j].ParameterType.Name;
            sb.Append(typeName + " " + pi[j].Name);
        }
        sb.Append(")");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
public class StackFrameModel
{
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    public string AssemblyFile { get; set; }
    public string CodeFile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It seems here that we are reimplementing something that is already implemented. I would like to take the stack trace and fix whatever is causing the bad parsing. Nevertheless, I appreciate this but I may use it only as last resort.

Comment: `Exception.StackTrace` property returns just a piece of string. You need to parse it to extract information from it; however, the `StackTrace` class allows you to get all the information related to the stack trace (not in text format).

Comment: Isn't there a direct way to parse the stack trace to JSON? What is name of the stack trace format by the way?

Comment: [Exception.StackTracte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.stacktrace?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) is a string property. It's just `ToString` of [StackTracte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) class which basically means: one kind of string representation of  the stack trace.

Comment: My approach is similar to what has been done in ASP.NET Core [ErrorPage](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Shared/ErrorPage/Views/ErrorPage.cshtml?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and ASP.NET [DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/DeveloperExceptionPage/DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.cs?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#L227)